# Android Floating button for delphi fmx application

Tags: android, delphi, button

I would like to know if it is possible to implement a custom button (inside a FMX application developed with RADstudio) which behaves like an Android floating button.

[Floating button (Android documentation)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html)

Edit #1:
Using RadStudio 10.4.x, I'm now able to set the property StyleLookup of TButton to "transparentcirclebuttonstyle" and using TCircle I can draw a button that looks like an Android floating button.

Comment: Yes, We can. You need to handle all the floating behavior manually. I recommend go with native Floating button only. It is easy and also saves your development time.

Comment: Thank you for the replay, what do you mean with "go with native floating button only?"

Comment: Already they have provided the floating button then why you want to achieve the same with custom approach?

Comment: Ok wait, I'm not able to find a button component inside RADstudio that behaves like an android floating button, so i thought I needed to implement it myself (that's why I said "custom")

Comment: yes you can, simply draw it yourself on the top of the form.

Comment: Why not to use SpeedButton on top of all controls?

Comment: dustypup Because when user clicks on SpeedButton - he sees a grey rectangle, not a circle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated: Btw you can use SpeedButton with this circle image, so you can skip some routines below.

---

Prepare a png image (better 3 images with 3 scales) with your button.

```
Scale 1 = 56x56
Scale 2 = 112x112
Scale 3 = 168x168
```

Place it in TImageList (usually in global Datamodule), add your image in list, and add 3 scales factor to a source image (Double click on item in "Source of images" list in ImageList), so one image in TImageList will have 3 scale factors. 
Place TGlyph on a form and select your image list there.

Set OnClick event in Form OnCreate (because Glyph1 has no OnClick by default in Object Inspector):

```
Glyph1.OnClick := Click;
Glyph1.HitTest := true;
```

In OnClick add this code to animate:

```
procedure TForm2.TestClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TAnimator.AnimateFloatWait(Glyph1, 'Opacity', 0.5, 0.2);
  TAnimator.AnimateFloat(Glyph1, 'Opacity', 1, 0.2);
end;
```

Or you can use TImage - it's even easier and less code than above.

Also you can use NativeAPI to draw Circle + image + shadow with antialiasing on Android/iOS with Firemonkey.
http://www.cnblogs.com/onechen 
https://github.com/rzaripov1990/ZMaterialComponents 
But it's slower than a simple image.